# How to display button on screen tap

Tags: flutter

I am displaying a network image in the app and I need to display a button when the user taps on the screen. until then it should stay hidden.
How can I do it?

```
return Scaffold(
      body: GestureDetector(
        onTap:  (){
          
        },
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
              image: NetworkImage(widget.img_url),
              fit: BoxFit.contain
            )
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a GestureDetector around your Container, in onTap function set a bool value to true what means show the button:

```
GestureDetector(child: Container(...), onTap: () { _show = true; })
```

And put your button somewhere like this:

```
_show ? RaisedButton() : null
```